# Como fazer consulta personalizada com JPA+Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, query, jpa, jpql

Olá,

Gostaria de saber uma forma elegante de fazer uma consulta personalizada usando **JPA**.

Basicamente eu quero executar a consulta e que ela me retorne uma lista de objeto, mas geralmente vai se tratar de uma consulta com **N tabelas** e só com os campos que eu precisarei.

Entendo que tenho que fazer o `POJO` do retorno da query, mas teria algum `annotation`  ou outra coisa pra me ajudar a fazer esse link entre o retorno da query e o objeto? Não quero ter que passar linha a linha instanciando o objeto e coluna a coluna preenchendo as propriedades dele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a palavra chave **NEW** da JPQL na query, especificando uma classe. Para cada linha retornada, será criada uma instância desta classe. E então você pode passar o tipo desta sua estrutura de dados como parâmetro quando for solicitar a query ao **EntityManager**.

Esta estrutura de dados (ou "classe") precisa declarar um construtor que receba os valores dos campos na ordem em que eles são selecionados na query.

Então, considerando esta estrutura de dados:

```
package org.learning;

class ContaAtrasada {
    final int idConta;
    final double valor;
    final int diasEmAtraso;

    ContaAtrasada(int idConta, double valor, int diasEmAtraso) {
        this.idConta = idConta;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.diasEmAtraso = diasEmAtraso;
    }
}
```

O método que executa a query ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
public List<ContaAtrasada> findContasAtrasadas() {
    return em.createQuery("select NEW org.learning.ContaAtrasada(c.idConta, c.valor, " +
            "today - c.dataVencimento as diasEmAtraso) " +
            "from Conta c where c.dataVencimento < today", ContaAtrasada.class)
            .getResultList();
}
```

Eu explicitei o namespace (*package*) da classe porque é muito importante informá-lo na sua query JPQL, já que a query pode ser executada em outro contexto onde a sua classe não estará diretamente acessível.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava... vou testar! =)